# PL/SQL: Update row based on ROWID

Tags: oracle, plsql, rowid

I am trying to update a row in a table which has no unique index.   So, I selected the ROWID of the row I want to update and now I want to update the row like this:

```
UPDATE MYTABLE SET MYCOLUMN = 0 WHERE ROWID = "AAAIWWAAFAAApwDADR"
```

MYCOLUMN is of type NUMBER(1)

I get the error:   `invalid identifier [SQL State=42000, DB Errorcode=904]`

Any idea why?

Comment: You could also consider the [`SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/sqloperations.htm#BABJCEIF) syntax, which implicitly uses `ROWID` so you don't have to deal with it, for a more general case where you aren't hard-coding the value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using single quotes:

```
UPDATE MYTABLE SET MYCOLUMN = 0 WHERE ROWID = 'AAAIWWAAFAAApwDADR'
```

Comment: Brilliant - thank you!   I will mark this answer as correct as soon as it will let me!

Answer (score 0):

The easier way is write at the end of your select the cmd `for update` it allow you to update the row that you desire.
**Obs**: I'm used to do that on  Oracle PL/SQL Developer.